# Returning values from database to WebMethod

Tags: c#, webmethod

I need to enter some value in the textbox end save it to the database.
But if there is a duplicate value then the value must not be saved.

Basically, string lvl is successfully passed to the WebMethod from front-end via ajax.

Procedure getDuplicate is a simple select that checks if there is a value of lvl is already stored in the database. And InsertObject procedure inserts the value in the database.
If the value(lvl) exists then the ID of that value is return and stored in the Count integer.

The problem is if Count is returned with id number then if statement works,
and if there is no value in the database Count just does not receive any values and the procedure fails and goes straight to the catch part of the code.

I think there's a problem with the returning type from a database when there is no value in it. It is not INT or something.
Can anyone help, please?

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
            public static void GetCollection(string lvl)
            {

              string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Connection"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conn))

                try
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdCount = new SqlCommand("getDuplicate", connection);
                    cmdCount.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
                    int count = (int)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();

                    if (count > 0)
                    {

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SqlCommand cmdProc = new SqlCommand("InsertObjekat", connection);
                        cmdProc.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmdProc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ObjekatName", lvl);
                        cmdProc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        //strMsg = "Saved successfully.";
                    }

                }
                catch
                {


                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();

                }

            return;
```

getDuplicate procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDuplicate]  

    @ObjekatName nvarchar(20)
    AS
    BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SELECT TOP 1000 [ObjekatID]
      ,[ObjekatName]

  FROM [MyApp].[dbo].[Objekat]
  WHERE  ObjekatName = @ObjekatName
    END
```

Comment: Could you please also add the code of stored procedure `getDuplicate` ?

Comment: It is added to the question. When theres no value it return value 0 when executed

Comment: "I think"...if you actually exposed the exception in your catch block you could find out for sure. A catch which just completely squashes exceptions is a very bad idea. But yeah maybe you should use `int?` (nullable int) to allow for a null return value. The ExecuteScalar documentation (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) tells you it can return `null`. You need to check not just whether `count` is > 0 but also whether it's null. "When theres no value it return value 0 when executed" is not true, based on your code.

Comment: Also `TOP 1000` seems unnecessary...how many rows are you expecting to return? The fact you're using ExecuteScalar suggests you only expect one single row with one single value. This would make sense, if you're looking for a single duplicate. This makes `TOP` meaningless, you can remove it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This was the solution
  var count = (string)cmdCount.ExecuteScalar();


                    if (count == null)


The returning type was null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your GetDuplicate proc as below. It will always return a value.

```js
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDuplicate]
@name nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @duplicateCount int
    SELECT @duplicateCount=count(*) FROM [dbo].[employee] WHERE name = @name
    RETURN @duplicateCount
END
```